# Use index in array as datavalue?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I have a DropdownList and its datasource is a list of string. I want the DataValue to be the index of the element in the list.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: So ddl.DataValue = "IndexOf"; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to Flem's solution, but simplier. It uses one overload of `Select` method, where next to current `item` it's `index` it being passed.

```
ddl.DataSource = arrayOfStrings.Select((text, index) => new { text, index })
                               .ToList();

ddl.DataValueField = "index"; 
ddl.DataTextField = "text";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Comment: @IIyaIvano I like it, though a comment on my post would have been appropriate. +1.

Comment: @flem I've almost ended writing my post, when I saw you posted yours, so it's not like I completely stolen your answer. Sorry if any bad thought come to your mind)

Answer (score 3):

You need a value to bind to rather than a calculation. Do this upfront with a strong class or in the following example with a quick and easy anonymous type.

```
List<string> ds = yourlist;
ddl.DataSource = yourlist
    .Select(s => new 
    { 
        Text = s, 
        Value = yourlist.IndexOf(s) 
    })
    .ToList();
ddl.DataValueField = "Value"; 
ddl.DataTextField = "Text";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, Notice im setting the data text and value fields to specific columns from my data set.

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from country", cn);
         SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         adp.Fill(ds);
         Dropdownlist1.DataSource = ds;
         Dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "CountryName";
         Dropdownlist1.DataValueField = IndexOf("CountryID");
         Dropdownlist1.DataBind();
```